# Passing selected rows in a DT::renderDataTable through further functions to render another another table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

First time poster and new to R as a whole, let alone Shiny, so any help is appreciated.

I am wanting to take values from selected rows in one datatable, perform some operations on those numbers (in this example's case that is finding the mean of the two numbers) and then rendering these to a second datatable which will now have a new number but the first column (the 'names' in this case) stays the same.
I hope the MRE below illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
tab <- data.frame(names = c("shelly","bob","jim","frank","jess"),
                  numbers = c(30,45,55,70,90),
                  numbers2 = c(16,34,91,76,83)) 
tab$numbers<- paste(tab$numbers,tab$numbers2, sep = ',')
tab<-tab[,-3]
    
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("simpleApp"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel (
      dataTableOutput("table"),
      dataTableOutput("select_table")
    )
  )
  
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(tab, selection='multiple')
  
  
  
  data3<- reactive({ 
    data.frame(tab[input$table_rows_selected,])})  
  
  output$select_table<-DT::renderDataTable({
    if(nrow(data3()) > 0) {
      transform(data3(), numbers = mean(tab[input$table_rows_selected]$numbers) 
#this is the part I'm having trouble with I think
    }
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is much appreciated, and thank you for your patience with me!
Cheers

Comment: Very good point Ronak and thank you for the link explaining. I have done my best to alter the question to fit your suggestion. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated, I just cannot figure this one out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
tab <- data.frame(names = c("shelly","bob","jim","frank","jess"),
                  numbers = c(30,45,55,70,90))

library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("simpleApp"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel (
      dataTableOutput("table"),
      dataTableOutput("select_table")
    )
  )
  
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(tab, selection='multiple')
  
 
    
    data3<- reactive({ 
      data.frame(tab[input$table_rows_selected,])})  
  
  output$select_table<-DT::renderDataTable({
    if(nrow(data3()) > 0) {
      transform(data3(), numbers = numbers - 12)
    }
    })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

For the update question you can change the calculation to -

```
  output$select_table<-DT::renderDataTable({
    if(nrow(data3()) > 0) {
      transform(data3(), numbers = sapply(strsplit(tab$numbers[input$table_rows_selected], ','), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))))
    }
  })
```

Comment: My apologies Ronak, I thought that would do it but it has not worked for me, I think because I oversimplified the MRE.
Instead of simply subtracting 12 I am trying to run a function on the value in the numbers column, so perhaps the following example might be better. In this example I would like to calculate the mean of the two numbers in the numbers column to be output into the new datatable, I have once again modified my question.
I really appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: YEP! thats it! I had played around with the apply functions but clearly had not got the syntax right. That's brilliant, thanks very much!